# Including time in RestSharp call returns empty response

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm new to creating API clients and RestSharp. I'm trying to use RestSharp to make a request to an API maintained by one of our vendors.  The API accepts two parameters of either to and from date or to and from date and time. The RestSharp request works when I use just a date for each parameter, but I receive an empty response when I use a date and time.

I've confirmed that the datetime format is correct (ISO 8601).

When I make the same request, including date and time, in Postman I receive a non-empty response. The URI generated by RestSharp and the one I've used in Postman match.

I've seen issues reported with RestSharp and deserialization, but I have not been able to find a issue similar to the once I'm facing reported.  Any insight is appreciated.

The RestSharp code is:

```
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://test.com")
            {
                Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken("API_CONSUMER_KEY", "API_CONSUMER_SECRET")
            };

            var client = new RestClient(options);
            var pathValue = "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123";
            var request = new RestRequest("/url/{pathVariable}/url", Method.Get).AddUrlSegment("pathVariable", pathValue);

            request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
            request.AddParameter("from", "2023-07-12T01:57:05");
            request.AddParameter("to", "2023-07-12T10:00:08");
            var fullUrl = client.BuildUri(request);

            var response = client.Execute(request).Content;
```

The response I get is:
[Empty response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeZlf.png)

I've confirmed that the URI generated by RestSharp matches URI that returns a non-empty response in Postman.  I'm expected both to return a non-empty response.

Comment: Have you tried including `Z` at the end of your `DateTime` string? ex. `2023-07-12T01:57:05Z` I believe this is a requirement for the ISO 8601 standard if you're not including an offset ex. `+01:00`

Comment: It should be something in your API. It works as normal for me using date and times. Maybe you are not really using the same parameters as you do in postman? Did you get the code from Postman (unlikely) or wrote yourself? Also what do you get if you just simply paste that generated fullUrl in browser?

Comment: @akseli, thanks for the reply.  I had not tried including `Z`, but I've given it a try on your suggestion.  Included it produced no change, I still received an empty response.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, I wrote the code myself.  Pasting the generated fullUrl produces a 500 error in a browser.  I haven't been able to find another way to confirm what is being used for the parameters other than inspected the generated URL.

Comment: Ah forgot your authentication issue. Maybe you can check Postman generated restsharp code (though it generates for old version that doesn't work as is).

Comment: Have you tried not doing `AddHeader("Accept", "*/*")` for your request? As far as I know, RestSharp should be able to automatically determine the correct value. If you want to force `JSON` deserialization using the `Execute` method, you can change the `Accept` header to `application/json`, but this shouldn't really be necessary.

Comment: @akseli, I get the same result when `AddHeader("Accept", "*/*")` is removed from the request.  Using `RestResponse response = client.Execute(request)` for the request allows me to better inspect the response.  I get `"StatusCode: Unauthorized, Content-Type: , Content-Length: 0)"` when including a time in the query parameters, and `"StatusCode: OK, Content-Type: application/xml, Content-Length: 563668)"` as a response with just a date.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, I tested with Postman generated Restsharp code, but has the same issue.  I only made changes to account for authentication.